# DataTable sort by sum of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datatable

I want to order a datatable by the sum of it's columns, e.g.

```
dtSummary.DefaultView.Sort = "(Calls Closed + New Calls Triaged + Overdue Calls Triaged) Asc";
```

I guess I could do this by adding an extra column and computing the sum values before the sort, but wondered if there was a simpler way to acheive this.